# FACEBOOK SDK Invoke in android - Error says found 2 version of android

Tags: android, facebook

I am learning how i can post my results in Facebook.   So i have followed this link tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

I am currently in Creating Your Facebook Connect Project place.  When i include this Facebook sdk in Add place i am getting the below error. How i can resolve this problem

```
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] Versions found are:
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] Path: C:\Users\Murugan\facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk]     Length: 349252
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk]     SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] Path: C:\Users\Murugan\Workspace6\facebookchk\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk]     Length: 627582
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk]     SHA-1: db0f122c99ef9f90dbab3fada6d191f2880cbb8e
[2013-12-30 13:15:16 - facebookchk] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: It clearly says that you have 2 jar file with same name android-support-v4.jar in different path.

Answer (score 2):

Delete **android-support-v4.jar** from the Facebook SDK libs folder.

Both projects should have same support library you can either download the same library in both projects with same signatures.

Answer (score 1):

`android-support-v4.jar` is the default support library to support older devices.

The problem you are facing arises when the **library project** and your **actual project** are using **two different versions of the support library**.

The best way to resolve errors like this is to ***delete*** the jars (from both the projects) and then download the latest one by doing **Right Click on Project-> Android Tools -> Download Support Library**. You should do the same for both the projects, so the library project and your workspace project are using the same version of the support library jar.

Answer (score 0):

This error will occur when two different version of same library exist in the project.

> You can do two things

```
 1. Delete any one android-v4 library from the project(either FB SDK or your project).
 2. Or Put same library in the both.
```